# What is initEvents() and should I use it in 2018?

Tags: javascript, events

I'm trying to understand the code of another programmer and there is a initEvents () method. Some articles tells that this is an outdated method, but I'm not sure.
Could you help me? What it is? And is it really outdated?

Comment: [read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent) you shouldn't use this...

Answer (score 9):

This is indeed a [deprecated method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent) which will `init the event before dispatching`, you should instead use the [Event constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event) which have a second argument for event initialisation and then dispatch the event as you like.
Something like this:

```
// create a look event that bubbles up and cannot be canceled

var evt = new Event("look", {"bubbles":true, "cancelable":false});
document.dispatchEvent(evt);

// event can be dispatched from any element, not only the document
myDiv.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Answer (score 1):

`initEvents` has been deprecated.

Instead use this to **Create Events** :

```
const customEvent = new Event("CustomEventEmmiter", {"bubbles":true, "cancelable":false});
document.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
```

And listen to it like this :

```
window.addEventListener("CustomEventEmmiter", function(){
  alert('CustomEventEmmiter TRIGGERED');
});
```

[Check out more about Events here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event)