# How to test angular event listeners?

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, angular7, angular-unit-test

I have the following code,
comp:

```
ngOninit() {
  window.addEventListner('oreantationChange' () =>  {
    this.sideNavbar();
  });
}
```

Here  I want to cover the above code and the following are my changes,
spec:

```
it ('-----',() => {
  spyOn(window,'addEventListner');
  window.addEventListner('oreantationChange' () =>  {
     expect(component.sideNavbar).toHaveBeenCalled()
  });
}
```

But the above test is not getting covered.

Can anyone please suggest me help.Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't `oreantationChange` be `orientationChange`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/orientationchange_event

Answer (score 1):

Beside changing `oreantationChange` to `orientationChange`, rewrite the test as follows.

```
it ('-----', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'sideNavbar');
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('orientationChange'));

    expect(component.sideNavbar).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Hi @uminder,  How to I pass arguments to orientationChange event ?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48170980/2358409