# mock window.addEventListener() method

Tags: angular, mocking, jasmine, window, addeventlistener

How could I test this code:

```
this.window.addEventListener('pathSelectedFromMfe', (customEvent: CustomEvent) => {
  this.window.location.href = customEvent.detail.path;
});
```

This is what I have tried:

Let's say that you want to test the `window.addEventListener()` method without modifying the `window.location.href` property when an event is received. Usually an easy way to do this would be by following this answer: [How to test angular event listeners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57674212/how-to-test-angular-event-listeners). As you can see, no mock is required in that case.

If you proceed with the previous solution for my code, the test will fail with an error like this:
`Some of your tests did a full page reload!`.

Next step for me was to find out how can I test just the `this.window.location.href = customEvent.detail.path;` line and this can be done by following this answer:
[Angular unit testing window.location.href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69537614/angular-unit-testing-window-location-href). As you can see, a mock is being used in this case.

Now I believe that this solution (by using a mock) could be modified to also test the `window.addEventListener()` method, but I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

So I have found a solution, but I am not sure whether it is the optimal one. Basically what I did was to mock the `window.addEventListener()` method but this implied that I couldn't use the `window.dispatchEvent()` method anymore in my test (maybe that one can be mocked as well, but I don't see how they can work together in that case).
These are the files that I had to create/modify to test my code:

**window-token.ts**

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const WindowToken = new InjectionToken('Window');

export function windowProvider() {
  return window;
}
```

**app.module.ts**

add this line to the providers array:

```
{ provide: WindowToken, useFactory: windowProvider }
```

**my.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { WindowToken } from './core/window-token/window-token';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class MyComponent {

  constructor(@Inject(WindowToken) private window) {
    this.window.addEventListener('pathSelectedFromMfe', (customEvent: CustomEvent) => {
      this.window.location.href = customEvent.detail.path;
    });
  }
}
```

**my.component.spec.ts**

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { WindowToken } from './core/window-token/window-token';
import { MyComponent } from './my.component';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

  let customPath = '';
  const windowMock = {
    location: {
      _href: '',
      set href(url: string) {
        this._href = url;
      },
      get href() {
        return this._href;
      }
    },
    addEventListener(event: string, callback: (customEvent: CustomEvent) => void) {
      callback(new CustomEvent(event, { detail: { path: customPath } }));
    }
  };

  beforeEach(
    waitForAsync(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [MyComponent],
        providers: [
          { provide: WindowToken, useValue: windowMock }
        ]
      }).compileComponents();
    })
  );

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should handle pathSelectedFromMfe window event', () => {
    const setHrefSpy = spyOnProperty(windowMock.location, 'href', 'set');

    customPath = '/search';
    // the constructor is called when we create the MyComponent, so we invoke the creation again to use the new value for customPath
    TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    expect(setHrefSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/search');
  });
});
```

I don't think this is the best solution because the `constructor` code is called straight away inside the `beforeEach()` method from the unit test when we call `TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);`. This means that we call `this.window.location.href = ''` before the unit test even starts.

Every time we want to test the code with a different value for the event that is received we need to call `TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);`, whereas when the real window object is used (like in the solution linked in my initial question message) we only need to dispatch a new event. Also in this solution the event has to be modified through an auxiliary variable, in my case the `customPath` string.

For now this solution works for me, but if anyone finds a better one, please add a response.

PS: the code is part of an Angular 13 project.